# Is there a language spec for clojure?

Tags: clojure, specifications

Is there a language specification for clojure?  Something that precisely defines the lexical syntax and grammar in EBNF or something similar?

The closest thing that I could find is the [clojure website](http://clojure.org), but that doesn't really quite meet the requirements of a language spec (despite being an absolutely wonderful resource).  If there is no spec, has our BDFL made mention of any plans for one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the closest thing to an official Clojure EBNF that you are likely to find.

https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/blob/3738a4fd768bcb0399630b7f6a6427a3066bdaa9/clojure-antlr-grammar/src/Clojure.g

Comment: You win this one, sir. Well played... well played.

Comment: https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/blob/3738a4fd768bcb0399630b7f6a6427a3066bdaa9/clojure-antlr-grammar/src/Clojure.g

Comment: BNF is just syntax (of which Clojure has almost none). It is a not a semantics.

Answer (score 18):

The grammar [linked by fogus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902857/578288), which was within the Eclipse plugin [Counterclockwise](https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw), is no longer used by that project and has been removed from it.

### `Clojure.g4`, an ANTLR grammar

For a more up-to-date ANTLR grammar for Clojure, see **[`Clojure.g4`](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/clojure/Clojure.g4)** ([permalink](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/9731faa7302014400c00028ec0708b76a5907711/clojure/Clojure.g4)) from [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4), a collection of “grammars written for ANTLR v4”. `Clojure.g4` is small and easy to read, and it has successfully parsed [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) and [`clojure.core`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) in the past, but that does not guarantee that it can parse all Clojure code correctly.

### Clojure’s parser, `LispReader.java`

The most authorative specification of Clojure’s syntax is [Clojure’s source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure) itself. Clojure does not use an abstract grammar, only a custom parser, but you can understand the grammar after careful study of the parser’s implementation. Here is Clojure’s parser: **[`LispReader.java`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java)** ([permalink](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/68fe71f0153bb6062754442c0a61c075b58fd9bc/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java)).

`LispReader.java` uses a few classes from other files in [the same directory](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang), such as [`LineNumberingPushbackReader`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LineNumberingPushbackReader.java), but most of the code is in that file. In `LispReader`, the main function is [`read`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/68fe71f0153bb6062754442c0a61c075b58fd9bc/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L223). `read` uses [`isWhitespace`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/68fe71f0153bb6062754442c0a61c075b58fd9bc/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L120) to ignore whitespace and commas. It also detects numbers and hands off the parsing to [`readNumber`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/68fe71f0153bb6062754442c0a61c075b58fd9bc/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L312). For most other symbols, such as `(` and `#`, `read` hands off interpretation to the objects in the [`macros` and `dispatchMacros` arrays](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/68fe71f0153bb6062754442c0a61c075b58fd9bc/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L89-L117). You can follow the code from there.

### clojure.tools.reader, a parser written in Clojure

There is also a Clojure reimplementation of `LispReader.java` called **[clojure.tools.reader](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader)**. [Its source code](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/reader.clj) might be easier to read than `LispReader`, since it is in Clojure, not Java. clojure.tools.reader has some [differences from `LispReader.java`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader#differences-from-lispreaderjava), which are mostly being able to read some minor extra syntaxes proposed for Clojure and handling errors better.

Answer (score 7):

There is no language specification. If there are any plans for one in the future, I haven't heard of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a syntax error or two:

```
user=> (defn)
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/defn at (REPL:1:1). 
() - failed: Insufficient input at: [:fn-name] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/defn-args
```

And

```
user=> (fn [3]) Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/fn at (REPL:1:1).
(3) - failed: Extra input at: [:fn-tail :arity-1 :params] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list
3 - failed: vector? at: [:fn-tail :arity-n :params] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list
```

It is clear that the syntax of the core macros is now (version 1.10) checked using `clojure.spec`. If and when the *Clojure in Clojure* project advances, we can expect `spec` to extend its reach into the compiler proper.

The point is that `spec` has full EBNF power, so the source code will then contain a full EBNF of the language. The notation is explained in [Clojure - clojure.spec: Rationale and Overview](https://clojure.org/about/spec):

> Sequences
>
> Specs for sequences/vectors use a set of standard regular expression
>   operators, with the standard semantics of regular expressions:
>
> ```
> cat - a concatenation of predicates/patterns
>
> alt - a choice of one among a set of predicates/patterns
>
> * - zero or more occurrences of a predicate/pattern
>
> + - one or more
>
> ? - one or none
>
> & - takes a regex op and further constrains it with one or more predicates
> ```

When will this happen? My (utterly uninformed) impression is that the core team are drowning in alligators and have almost forgotten their original intention to drain this swamp.

---

A previous answer referring to `spec` in general terms for Clojure 1.9 was deleted. I think its use to define and check macro syntax is new with 1.10.

Comment: More info about [core.specs.alpha](https://github.com/clojure/core.specs.alpha), the library that generates the error messages you quoted: it is “a Clojure library containing specs to describe Clojure core macros and functions.” Clojure 1.9+ depends on that library. Currently, all of its specs are defined in [src/main/clojure/clojure/core/specs/alpha.clj](https://github.com/clojure/core.specs.alpha/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/specs/alpha.clj).